# Autogenerate DTO elements when loading an XML for Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, dto

Suggest me a proper solution for autogenerating DTO elements when loading a proper XML for Deserialization.

This is my DTO

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace GHelper.DTO
{
    public class ElementsDTO
    {
        [XmlRoot("GalLC")]
        public class FareBB
        {
            [xmlElement("Ip")]
            public string strIp { get; set; }
            [xmlElement("Port")]
            public int intPort { get; set; }
            [xmlElement("Type")]
            public int intPort{ get; set; }
            [xmlElement("Email")]
            public string strEmail{ get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my XML

```
<GalLC>
    <Ip>192.168.2.100</Ip>
    <Port>5051</Port>
    <Type></Type>
    <Email></Email>
</GalLC>
```

The problem is: when i am getting a lengthy XML, I will consume lots of time to create a DTO for it.
Please suggest me something about creating a DTO automatically.

Comment: Do you have an XML schema (XSD)? There are tools to generate class definitions from these. Without that, any tool would be guessing what the data types and structure is.

Comment: I may get different XMLs. So the structure will be also changes right?.

Comment: I hope you understand that i am trying to do Deserialization into Objects.

Comment: Are you extracting every element from the XML?  There are lots of methods for parsing an XML besides using serialization.  The time to write the parsing code and the time to write then serialization code is about equal.

Comment: @SusajSNair yes.  But you cannot generate a class/object from your sample file - you need an XML schema.  How would it know that only one IP is allowed?  How would it know `Port` is an integer?

Comment: @ CharlesMager I have found few  ways to create XML Schema in internet for my xml.
Therefor, i think now its easy for u to suggest me a perfect solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it sounds like you've worked out how to get an XML schema definition (XSD) [you could use XSD.exe to generate the classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s2x1sy7(v=vs.110).aspx) or there's [even online tools](http://www.httputility.net/xsd-to-csharp-vb-class.aspx) for it... And if you want something really custom, you could look into [T4 Text Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).

Comment: Thanks man it partially helped me..like, to create classes. What should i do for De serializing.. :(

Comment: From that point, you should be able to use an [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx) or similar.